# How to convert a column which of class data.frame to an integer so it can work with sqldf

Tags: r, dataframe, sqldf

I am working with a data set and I need to run several queries one after the other in order to create some new variables. The problem is that  after the first query, the new variable which is created is of class data.frame. This means that subsequent queries do not run, because as explained in the following post:  [R- sqldf error raw vs double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676537/r-sqldf-error-raw-vs-double)
... "The columns of your data.frame cannot be of class data.frame for sqldf to work"

The problem is that the above post does not tell me how to solve this problem. You can replicate my problem with the following example:

```
set.seed(999)
dt <- data.frame("x"=rnorm(150, 600,195))
sapply(dt, class)
library(sqldf)
dt$x2 <- sqldf("SELECT CASE
WHEN x>999 THEN x / 100
WHEN x>99  THEN x/10
ELSE x
END as x2
FROM dt")
sapply(dt, class)
```

The output of the last line shows that the class of X2 is *data.frame*. This means that when I try to run my next query, it will not work.

```
dt$x3 <- sqldf("SELECT CASE
WHEN x>999 THEN x - 100
WHEN x>99  THEN x - 10
ELSE x + 10
END as x3
FROM dt")
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Comment: You are assigning a data.frame to a column in 'dt'

Comment: Possibly `dt$x2 <- unlist(sqldf("SELECT CASE ...)` will work.

Comment: I have provided a simplified version of my queries, which is based on a single table. In my actual research project, I am working with a relational database and I need to use sqldf to run the queries based on multiple tables.

Comment: If you are returning multiple variables at once, then you might need to use `cbind` (assuming order is preserved) or `merge` on some IDs.

Comment: What is wrong with getting your result set back as a data frame?  What do you plan to do with the results of this query?

Comment: Instead of `dt$x2 <- sqldf("SELECT CASE ...` try `dt <- sqldf("SELECT x, CASE ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Add `[,1]` to the end of the `sqldf()`

```
set.seed(999)
dt <- data.frame("x"=rnorm(150, 600,195))
sapply(dt, class)
library(sqldf)
dt$x2 <- sqldf("SELECT CASE
WHEN x>999 THEN x / 100
WHEN x>99  THEN x/10
ELSE x
END as x2
FROM dt")[,1]
sapply(dt, class)
```

`sqldf` returns a data frame. The sub setting pulls out the column.