# R - Error in rsqlite_bind_rows(rs@ptr, value) :

Tags: sql, r

I hope you can help me with this.

I've imported 3 json files in R and used streamed in to get 3 df's on which I can do queries with sqldf. On 2 of them it works fine, but on the third one I get this error when using:

```
sqldf('select * from fixfull where checksum is "121"')
Error in rsqlite_bind_rows(rs@ptr, value) : 
  Can only bind lists of raw vectors (or NULL)
```

I get the same error message for all other queries on this df. Don't know what is wrong specifically, and can't find other related errors on stackoverflow.

Could someone help?

Thanks a lot!!

Vmontreal

Comment: Do you mean `where checksum IS '121'`?

Comment: That doesn't matter if I use single or double quotes there, if I use single quotes there, then I use double at beginning or end of the query. I get same error when I do: select checksum from fixfull or any other column. It's now how I perform the queries.

on the other 2 df's that are imported as json file i don't get this error.

Comment: Checksum is a builtin function in SQL Server (not sure about SQL Lite). Maybe try wrapping the column in identifiers?

Comment: If I use this query i get the same error: sqldf("select * from fixfull where msgseqnum IS '1'")
Error in rsqlite_bind_rows(rs@ptr, value) : 
  Can only bind lists of raw vectors (or NULL)

Comment: Yeah I don't think your issue is SQL at all then. Maybe this [R thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33677162/7948962) will help you out.

Comment: No it's not the sql itself, I think there's something with the frame and that's why sqldf is not working, I just don't know why. Thanks for forwarding the R thread. But I read that already, and it's not helping me, that's why I posted a separate question

Comment: I found the error already. One column had an array of multiple values in it, that's why sqldf told me, can only perform on raw vectors. Thanks anyway for your support @JacobH

Comment: *I think there's something with the frame and that's why sqldf is not working* ... that is why we ask for data. This is a data-specific issue. Please post a working json (1st or 2nd) and non-working json (#3) and fuller code with all `library` lines of your process instead of one-line snippets. This will help us reproduce your error.